# Laravel 5.3 - How to perform a query across multiple databases?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

We currently have multiple databases physically located in different places. The structures of them are exactly identical. We do this instead of partitioning due to some legal regulations (and for *most* of the times, we do queries to only one of them).

But sometimes we need to do the cross-database stuff and we could know which databases to query based on the request. I know this could be done with a loop in each of the APIs but that would be rather ugly and I want a programmatic way (we've got a number of APIs which could potentially get a cross-database query).

For example, could there be something like:

```
$batchModel = new Batch();
// an array instead of a string here
$batchModel->setConnection(['region1', 'region2']);
$batchModel->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.. As far as I know Laravel doesn't natively support this.

I can think of a way to make this work:

You can create multiple databases in your .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=region1
DB_HOST=adomain.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And another one:

```
DB_CONNECTION=region2
DB_HOST=anotherdomain.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then add it to your `database config`:

```
'region1' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

**Do the same for region2.**

Now extend the `Eloquent` class and add a method like "setMultipleConnections":

```
public method setMultipleConnections($databases, Model $model) {

   $collection = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
   // Loop over $databases array and for each one of them get the collection. 
   foreach ($databases as $database) {
       $model = new $model;
       $model->setConnection($database);
       $model->get();

       $collections->merge($model);
   }

   return $collection;

}
```

Then I think you can call methods like `all` and `find` on that collection.

*None of this works, it's just a quick draft. I think you know what I'm trying to achieve here. Is this something that you're looking for?*

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. But I cannot come up with a proper to implement it.

Comment: The way I did it wouldn't be a proper way for you to implement it?

Comment: Well the code I wrote isn't testing and probably doesn't work right off the bat. It's just to illustrate a way to approach this problem :)

Comment: I did something similar by passing a callback which returns a collection to a function. Initially, I expected a function that accepts a model and a query builder and performs the query over all regions but I failed to find the way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the database based on the request I would go for a middleware i.e:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{        
    if( $request->has('something') ) {
        config(['database.default' => $request->something]);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: You completely misunderstood me, man. I meant whether there's a concise way to do the loop through all databases, not how to set the default one.

Comment: You're right I completely misunderstood the problem, Frederick. I reread your question and I dont have a good solution for what you ask.